# unwanted class with display: none making content invisible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting unwanted `class (.page)` as the page loads with css property `display: none`, which makes the content invisible. I haven't inserted any `class(.page)`. I have tried to undo the css property none to block via a JS but its not working. I can't figure out the problem. Its strange.

Here is the html that I actually coded:

```
<div class="deck-background"></div>
<div id="page">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content" class="column" role="main">
            <a id="main-content"></a>
              <the main html content sits here> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This I am getting as the page loads. Please note two new divs with class (.page).

```
<div class="deck-background"></div>
<div id="page">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content" class="column" role="main">
            <div class="page" style="display: block;">
                <a id="main-content"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="page" style="display: none;">
            <the main html content sits here>  
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    window.onload = function() {
        function showHide(id) {
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('.page')
    if( el && el.style.display == 'block')    
        el.style.display = 'none';
    else 
        el.style.display = 'block';
}
    }
</script>
```

Comment: seems like you have a script in your html page adding that extra div and also styling...

Comment: where are you calling showHide ...that code is missing..can you add that

Comment: @Geeky, there is window.onload I need the function to be called automatically.

Comment: How can it get called automatically. Even if you keep it in window.onload,call to this function should either be triggered by an event or you should call manually ,where are you doing either of this

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JS

```
window.onload = function() {
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.page');
[].forEach.call(el, function(el){
    el.style.display = "block";
   });
```

}